# Angular: Display local time in Dublin

Tags: angular

using pipe I can display time for different timezones using ISO timezone

```html
<li class="py-2">
  <span class="text-white-50">Bolivia <small>Sucre</small>&thinsp;:
    <span class="time">{{ now | date:'longTime':'BOT' }}</span></span>
</li>
```

But what how about Dublin or Paris and without having to rebuild app after daylight saving time changes?

Dublin is in IST but seems to be missing and could not find what I should put for Paris.

Is there a easy way to simply use 'Europe/Paris' or 'Europe/Dublin' ?

Seemed crazy to me that for something as basic as that, I could not find a simple way to do it.  What kind of use is a GMT+1 in the real world (do we have to find out when each country changes to daylight saving)?

ngx-moment is of no help...

someone comes up with a simple practical solution could help many :)

Comment: Paris GMT+2 `{{ now | date:'longTime':'+0200' }}` Dublin GMT+1 `{{ now | date:'longTime':'+0100' }}` Is this helps?

Comment: STA: thanks, but this is not useful... Found that too, but not going to come back edit app each time Paris or Dublin changes to daylight saving :-/

Comment: I find  article about DST mabe this help You 
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html

Comment: @TomaszVizaint I'm sure there is a way to use 'Europe/Paris' but those who found it are keeping it secret ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had put up un answer pointing this article that had the solution I adopted.  For some reason the answer disappeared before I got to accepting it as answer.

https://medium.com/@markuretsky/extend-angular-datepipe-for-timezone-abbreviations-support-9b65fa0807fb

moment-date.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
/**
* A moment timezone pipe to support parsing based on time zone abbreviations
* covers all cases of offset variation due to daylight saving.
*
* Same API as DatePipe with additional timezone abbreviation support
* Official date pipe dropped support for abbreviations names from Angular V5
* Credits: https://medium.com/@markuretsky/extend-angular-datepipe-for-timezone-abbreviations-support-9b65fa0807fb
*/
@Pipe({
  name: 'momentDate'
})
export class MomentDatePipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    value: string | Date,
    format: string = 'mediumDate',
    timezone: string = 'Europe/Paris'
  ): string {
    const timezoneOffset = moment(value).tz(timezone).format('Z');
    return super.transform(value, format, timezoneOffset);
  }
}
```